# How to Call MessagingCenter.Send from GenericRepository

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use Xamarin MessagingCenter.Send  from GenericRepository.
but its not working.

My Code is like this.

```
public class GenericRepository : IGenericRepository
{
   private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;
    private readonly ISettingsService _settingsService;
    public GenericRepository(ISettingsService settingsService, IDialogService  dialogService)
    {
        _settingsService = settingsService;
        _dialogService = dialogService;
    }
    public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri)
    {
          var httpClient =await CreateHttpClient();
            //My work here
            return default(T);
    }

private async Task<HttpClient> CreateHttpClient()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_settingsService.AccessTokenSetting))
        {
            if (_settingsService.TokenExpireOnSetting.HasValue)
            {
                if (DateTime.UtcNow > _settingsService.TokenExpireOnSetting)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "RefreshTokenSubscribe");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                    return httpClient;
                }
            }

        }

        return httpClient;
    }
}
```

[GenericRepository Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCyZd.png)

[ViewModel Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vy45.png)

[InitializeApp Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck37Q.png)

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [I downvoted because images of code are not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) As others have indicated, please include a [mcve] **as text**.

Comment: source code is added please review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below

```
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<GenericRepository>(this, "RefreshTokenSubscribe", (obj) =>
            {
                RefreshTokenSubscribe();
            });
```

I have only added to ( ) to the object here. And Subscribe to the message in ViewModel Constructor.